# How can I make an alphabetical keyboard with only numberpad keys

Tags: python, keyboard, numpad

I am trying to make a keyboard but I want to make it work using a numpad only and the buttons on there however my code doesn't seem to work for the a and b part. I have commented which part.

```
if "1" in line:
    if kytype == 'a':
        kytype = "k"
    elif kytype == 'b': #when this part is runned it prints a 'b' instead
        kytype == "u"   # of a 'u'
    elif kytype == " ":
        kytype = "a"
elif "2" in line:
    if kytype == 'a':
            kytype = "l"
    elif kytype == 'b':
            kytype == "v" #it happens here too and instead of printing a
    elif kytype == " ":   # 'v' it prints a 'b'
            kytype = "b"
#I haven't done the rest of the code for other letters because of the
#problem
elif line = 'ins':
    print(kytype)
    kytype = " "
```

Comment: Confused on what the purpose is. Are you trying to make [something like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Mobile_phone_keyboard.svg)?

Comment: If it is the case, that's the best XY catch I've seen in a long time.

Comment: Sort of, I'm trying to make it so that you type the number associated with a letter (1 = a) then when you type a key it then prints it. For example I type 11 then hit a key then it should print the letter 'k'